# How to modify the z-index of Material-UI <Select> dropdown div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am rendering an `<AppBar>` with a large z-index value (using `withStyles`, it has a value of `theme.zIndex.modal + 2` which computes to `1202`).

The reason for this is to ensure my `<Drawer>` component remains hidden behind the `<AppBar>` when it's opened (i.e. a clipped drawer).

However when I render a `<Select>` component within my appbar, the 'dropdown' div does not have a large enough z-index value to be displayed, and so it ends up being hidden behind the appbar.

A basic example is as follows:

```
let Test = ({classes}) => (
  <AppBar className={classes.appbar} elevation={2} position='relative'>
    <Toolbar>
      <Select>
        <MenuItem>{"Item 1"}</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>{"Item 2"}</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </Toolbar>
  </AppBar>
)

const styles = theme => ({
  appbar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.modal + 2,
    margin: 0
  }
})

Test = withStyles(styles)(Test);
```

Overriding the z-index on any of `<Select>`'s exposed classes does not seem to fix my problem. How can I ensure `<Select>` appears in front of `<AppBar>`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `style` attribute on all components in `Material-UI`

```
<Select style={{zIndex: X}}>
   ...
</Select>
```

Cf: https://v0.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field
For details about all the available styles attributes.

Comment: Yes I know. That style gets applied to the root element. But like I said, modifying the z-index on any of `<Select's>` exposed elements does not solve my problem. Likely because it's using a `<Modal>`. Also, extra curly braces are needed in your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can use PaperProps on Drawer component to adjust zindex instead of changing Select component's zindex.